# Django Templates: Writing an if filter to get around dividing by Zero

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using template tags to divide two numbers. The problem occurs when the denominator is zero. I am trying to use if with operators but this seems to not be working.

```
<td class="data">${% if nnl_asof_mtdgoal %}{{ nl_mtdgoal.get_mtd_newloansgoal|div:nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals |floatformat:"2"| intcomma }}{% endif %}
```

This gives me this error

```
File "C:\pycharm-virtenv\DjangoPostgres\lib\site-packages\mathfilters\templatetags\mathfilters.py" in div
  72.         return nvalue / narg

Exception Type: ZeroDivisionError at /reports/goals/
Exception Value: float division by zero
```

As it should since its division by zero. When I try this:

```
<td class="data">${% if nnl_asof_mtdgoal !="0" %}{{ nl_mtdgoal.get_mtd_newloansgoal|div:nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals |floatformat:"2"| intcomma }}{% endif %}
                    </td>
```

I get this error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /reports/goals/
Exception Value: Could not parse the remainder: '!="0"' from '!="0"'
```

I know this has to be an easy one but I cannot seem to figure out how to only draw the table if the division is True, i.e. not dividing by zero.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space after `!=` in your template tag, i.e.

```
{% if nnl_asof_mtdgoal != "0" %}
```

If `nnl_asof_mtdgoal` was an integer and not a string, you would do:

```
{% if nnl_asof_mtdgoal != 0 %}
```

Since you use `div:nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals` in your template, it looks as if `nnl_asof_mtdgoal` is not an integer, so you should change the check to:

```
{% if nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals != 0 %}
```

Note that Django encourages you to keep logic out of the templates. It might be better to try to shift the calculation (and checking for zero) to the view.

Comment: It is an integer and I tried the space but still get the float division by zero error. The reason why I am doing this in the template is these values do not need to write to the database and are only a result of other numpy calculations I have going on in the back end due to user input.

Comment: You are checking whether `nnl_asof_mtdgoal` is equal to zero, but you are dividing by `nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals`. It doesn't matter whether the values need to write to the database or not. If you have `nnl_asof_mtdgoal` in the view, then you can do calculations in the view.

Comment: Thanks! I still cannot get it to recognize if there is or is not a zero. I tried `code`if nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals !=0 and still received the float error. I will have to look into running these calculations outside of the template. Currently I am doing calculations in another .py file and using the templates tags to point to it so my views.py file only has views related code. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the value of `{{ nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals }}` in the template?

Comment: It is an integer that is the product of two variables which -depending on the day- could yield a zero. I am dividing `nl_mtdgoal.get_mtd_newloansgoal` by this number to find the average.

Comment: No, I don't mean what does the value represent, I mean what does the template output when you do `{{ nnl_asof_mtdgoal.get_mtd_numnewloansgoals}}`?

Comment: I just wanted to let know that I appreciate your help and I ultimately just moved the calculations out of the templates and into my other calculations.py file. I wish I had the time to figure out a way but given that maybe Django knows best, I will stick to the suggested format.

Comment: It's a shame we didn't figure out what the problem was in the template, but I think that moving the logic from the template to the `calculations.py` file is probably a better solution anyway.

Comment: I agree and would like to figure it out once this project is done if your up for it. Unfortunately the deadline for the project is coming up and I need to move on. Good news is I can manipulate the logic better, faster, and more concisely in the `calculations.py` file.